# Как правильно организовать проход точек на матрице?

Tags: lua

Есть некоторое кол-во точек. Каждая из них имеет координаты по XY. Располагаются они неравномерно, а расстояние между ними может быть огромно.
Из-за чего возникает следующий вопрос: "как правильно огранизовать перебор всех этих точек, чтобы они могли с помощью собственных функций взаймодействовать друг с другом?".

Ранее точки хранились в неотсортированном одномерном массиве в виде таблиц, содержащих координаты и пр. В этом случае при попытке, например, получить соседние точки на определённом расстоянии от точки, пришлось бы снова делать проход по всем точкам в отдельном или следующем проходе.

Хотелось бы получить совет по этому поводу.